# (Flutter) Getting this errors " flutter_blurhash-0.7.0 : DecoderCallback' not found " when using cached_network_image To load image on slider

Tags: android, flutter

I'm using => cached_network_image:
git:
url: https://github.com/Carapacik/flutter_cached_network_image.git
path: cached_network_image

to cache my images for my slider and in get this errors.

Here's the Error code:

[image]

and Here's my pubspec.yaml code:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  dio: ^5.3.2
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.3
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  cached_network_image:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/Carapacik/flutter_cached_network_image.git
      path: cached_network_image

  flutter_blurhash: ^0.7.0
```

flutter version: Flutter 3.14.0-12.0.pre.46
dart version: Dart SDK version: 3.2.0-97.0.dev (dev)

I have tried to do flutter clean => flutter pub get => flutter run  and nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

You should delete `cached_network_image` from `pubspec.yaml`
and delete any file related its,
to do that go to

```
C:\Users\*UserComputerName*\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev
```

and delete any folder first name ("cashed")
after that go to terminal in your project

```bash
flutter clean

flutter pub get
```

Note: You will use other way to show your network image in project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What other way would that be? Maybe suggestions would be great?

Answer (score 0):

For me I was using an older version of `cached_network_image` which was `3.0.0`

on upgrading to `3.3.0` it was resolved.