# Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found flutter_map: ^0.13.1

Tags: flutter, dart, fluttermap

Ihave this error:
../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_map-0.13.1/lib/src/layer/tile_provider/network_image_with_retry.dart:36:34: Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.
NetworkImageWithRetry key, DecoderCallback decode) async {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_map-0.13.1/lib/src/layer/tile_provider/network_image_with_retry.dart:36:34: Error: 'DecoderCallback' isn't a type.
NetworkImageWithRetry key, DecoderCallback decode) async {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
I use this version of flutter_map: ^0.13.1 and my sdk version is sdk: '>=2.18.5 <3.0.0' help me please

I can't use other version because I have a big project working with this version

Comment: checkout this answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78053975/11044933) might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You probably have flutter > 13.3 version.
Since 13.3, flutter has changed DecoderCallback for DecoderBufferCallback.

Try to install a previous version of flutter

https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/3-13-deprecations